# Sql Datetime throw Error converting data type varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have this stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET DATEFORMAT DMY -- This line of code was added by my trying to avoid the problem
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Hotel_RegistroHuesped 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @p_accion                             int 
, @p_IdRegistroHuesped                  numeric (18,0)
, @p_IntIdHabitacion                    int 
, @p_CheckInFecha                       datetime 
, @p_CheckOutFecha                      datetime
, @p_CheckOutFechaEsperada              datetime 
, @p_NumIdTerceroCondicionesComerciales int 
, @p_StrUsuarioCrea                     usuario  = suser_sname
, @p_DatfechaCrea                       datetime = getdate
, @p_StrUsuarioModifica                 usuario  = NULL
, @p_DatFechaModifica                   datetime = NULL
, @p_ListaHuespedes                     char(400)= null
AS
BEGIN

END
```

Nothing special or strange to me but really I'm stuck when try to execute like this

```
set dateformat dmy 

exec dbo.sp_Hotel_RegistroHuesped 
    @p_accion=1,
    @p_IdRegistroHuesped=0,
    @p_IntIdHabitacion=37,
    @p_CheckInFecha='11/03/2014 21:48:28.301',
    @p_ListaHuespedes='',
    @p_CheckOutFecha=NULL,
    @p_CheckOutFechaEsperada='11/03/2014 22:48:28.301',
    @p_NumIdTerceroCondicionesComerciales=1
```

It always throw

> Mens 8114, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento sp_Hotel_RegistroHuesped, Línea 0
>   Error converting data type varchar to datetime

This is a variant that I'm was trying

```
set dateformat dmy 
exec dbo.sp_Hotel_RegistroHuesped 
    @p_accion=1,
    @p_IdRegistroHuesped=0,
    @p_IntIdHabitacion=37,
    @p_CheckInFecha='11/03/2014 21:48:28',
    @p_ListaHuespedes='',
    @p_CheckOutFecha=NULL,
    @p_CheckOutFechaEsperada='11/03/2014 22:48:28',
    @p_NumIdTerceroCondicionesComerciales=1
```

Just removing the milliseconds part.

What is the proper way to execute this sp?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Who ever names the stored procedures with `sp_` should be fired.

Comment: Tks a lot, really I removed some parths of the name. But why @FreshPrinceOfSO is so Angry?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez No anger, just common sense.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO ok. but seems like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the conversion of the date format you're using (`'11/03/2014 22:48:28'`) depends on the language settings (order of day/month, etc.), it's better to use the ISO standard date format that should be recognised correctly - `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`:

```
'2014-03-11T22:48:28'
```

Comment: Tks for your help... but there is a ``SET`` command to configure this option? just because i have several SP calls and others Works great.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez See for example this question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398921/how-does-sql-server-decide-format-for-implicit-datetime-conversion.

Comment: Tks a lot Szymon, but at least found the problem, It was at the Sp definition  this line ``@p_DatfechaCrea                       datetime = getdate`` doesn't work as I expected. Maybe a collation problem. After remove this line eve3rything Works fine, but Your recomendation is totally valid. i'm going to implement it. TKS