# SQL Server: the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to insert the date and time in two ways which is shown as below:

Table: ft

```
create table ft
(
   columndate datetime,
   columntime datetime
)
```

Insertion of records: format 1

```
insert into ft values('2014-12-25', '01:55:56');
```

Insertion of records: format 2

```
insert into ft values('25-12-2014', '01:45:54');
```

**Note**: Yeah! Of course I want to insert only date for first column that is `columndate` and time for second column that is `columntime` and I want to use `datetime` datatype for that. For both the format of insertion I am getting the same error which is shown as below:

Error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: What is 25 Hrs may be this is giving error

Comment: Sorry! That was the typo. I apologies.

Comment: In the first query you are entering the date in the format `YYYY-MMM-DD` but in the second Insert you are providing the insert as `DD-MM-YYYY` thats giving you the error

Comment: Why are you using `DATETIME` if you only want to store the time? Use the most appropriate datatype - `TIME(n)` !!

Comment: You should use parameters from whatever runtime you're using, makes this much easier to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all about conversions and datatypes.

First, implicit conversion is dangerous. Just to know, take a look at this link: [How does SQL Server decide format for implicit datetime conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398921/how-does-sql-server-decide-format-for-implicit-datetime-conversion)

I usually use this format: 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'

It is not a problem to store just the day, but as suggested in comment, I recommend to use date type and time type.

Store only time in datetime type is not possible. If, for any reason, you really need to do this, you must do like in old days, when datetime was the only type usable, and insert your time with a default date, something like 19000101.

This:

```
insert into ft values('2014-12-25', '01:55:56');
```

Will be something like:

```
insert into ft values('20141225', '19000101 01:55:56');
```