# Error 242 when trying to insert a date with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Why when I try to insert this string into a "datetime" column of an SQL Server database table an error message with code 242 appears:

```
'2012-11-16 00:00:00.000'
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Server: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data
type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

This error doesn't appear if for example I try to insert this value:

```
'2012-11-16 15:00:00.000'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398921/how-does-sql-server-decide-format-for-implicit-datetime-conversion

Comment: CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-11-16 00:00:00.000') does not work!

Comment: insert into Table values ('CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-11-16 00:00:00.000') does not work...

Comment: how can you insert like that change the data type or declare the statement in table variable to insert

Comment: insert into Table values ('2012-11-15 20:51:59.998') does not work too, BUT WHY.

Comment: declare @t datetime =  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-11-16 00:00:00.000') INSERT INTO TABLE Select @t

Comment: Jonathan read the solition of Stefano Steiger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert it as `'2012-11-16T00:00:00.000'`

if you don't need the time, insert it as

```
'20121116'
```

Those are the ISO formats for datetime/date respectively. 
As with all other formats, you get problems depending on the language of the user that the SQL statement runs at.

You can also get problems like that with months/days, and it's not always apparent.

e.g. if you parse a string like `'01/01/2015'`, it will always work. 
But when you get to `'01/13/2015'`, you run into problems, because English uses `month/day/year`, while for example German uses `day/month/year`, and 13 is not a valid month...

In your case, it's somehow misinterpreting time, and that can lead to all kinds of strange errors.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, this is the real solution

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I discovered my SQL agent was using UK English `day/month/year` so I changed it to US English `month/day/year` and it worked. This was despite the text date was actually `year-month-day`