# Why does my complex 'mysql' query always returns query result 'count' as 0?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, filter, laravel-query-builder

I am writing code for filter search where user selects atleast one option from a list of 3 checkboxes then I have to write a query for the selected options(checkboxes). If I try to run my code then I am getting "query result count as equals to zero which means $count=0". Previously when I wrote code for the first time it has worked fine but now its not working.

My form is :

```
<form id="my_form_id" method="post" action="{{ action('MyController@store') }}"">
<div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="suppliers" name="suppliers">suppliers</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="campaign" name="campaign">campaign</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="clients" name="clients">clients</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="start_date">From:</label><input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="start_date">From:</label><input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" id="process" class="btn btn-primary submit">Run Report</button>
</div>
```

My MySql Table Structure & data is: lead_audit

Structure:

```
ColumnName  DataType  Length
  id         int      11
supplier_id  int      11
source       varchar  255
client_id    int      11
campaign_id  varchar  255
data         text 
received     datetime
errors       blob
disposition  varchar  255

id  supplier_id  source  client_id  campaign_id  data  received       errors  disposition
1   6            6          1       56           ---   2017-07-07 11:19:25  False  Accepted
1   6            6          1       56           ---   2017-07-07 11:19:25  False  Accepted
```

My Query is below:

```
if(isset($request->suppliers) && $request->suppliers == 'suppliers'){
            $results->leftjoin('suppliers AS s', 's.id', '=', 'l.supplier_id')
                    ->addSelect('s.name AS Supplier')
                    ->groupBy('s.name')
                    ->orderBy('s.name');
}
if(isset($request->source) && $request->source == 'source'){
            $results->addSelect('l.source AS Source')
                    ->groupBy('l.source')
                    ->orderBy('l.source');
            //$results->leftjoin('source AS so', 'so.id', '=', 'l.source_id')
}
if(isset($request->campaign) && $request->campaign == 'campaign'){
            $results->leftjoin('campaigns AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'l.campaign_id')
                    ->addSelect('c.name AS Campaign')
                    ->groupBy('c.name')
                    ->orderBy('c.name');
}    
if(isset($request->clients) && $request->clients == 'clients'){
            $results->leftjoin('clients AS cl', 'cl.id', '=', 'l.client_id')
                    ->addSelect('cl.name AS Client')
                    ->groupBy('cl.name')
                    ->orderBy('cl.name');
} 
$queryResults = $results->addSelect('l.disposition AS Disposition')
                ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) as Count')
                ->whereBetween('l.received', [$start, $end])
                ->groupBy('l.disposition')
                ->orderBy('l.disposition')
                ->get()->toArray();
$count = count($queryResults);
echo "Count: ".$count;exit;

if($count > 0){
  $results = array_map(function($item) {
            return (array)$item;
        }, $queryResults);
  return Excel::create('my_excel_name', function($excel) use ($results) {
            $excel->sheet('sheet_name', function($sheet) use ($results) {
                $sheet->fromArray($results);
            });
        })->setFilename($filename)
        ->download('csv');
} else{
        \Session::flash('error','No data has been found.');
        return redirect('my_controller/create');
    }
```

Resulting query is:

```
array:1 [▼
0 => array:3 [▼
"query" => "select `s`.`name` as `Supplier`, `l`.`source` as `Source`, `c`.`name` as `Campaign`, `cl`.`name` as `Client`, `l`.`disposition` as `Disposition`, COUNT(*) as Count from `lead_audit` as `l` left join `suppliers` as `s` on `s`.`id` = `l`.`supplier_id` left join `campaigns` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `l`.`campaign_id` left join `clients` as `cl` on `cl`.`id` = `l`.`client_id` where `l`.`received` between ? and ? group by `s`.`name`, `l`.`source`, `c`.`name`, `cl`.`name`, `l`.`disposition` order by `s`.`name` asc, `l`.`source` asc, `c`.`name` asc, `cl`.`name` asc, `l`.`disposition` asc ◀"
"bindings" => array:2 [▼
  0 => "2017-07-01"
  1 => "2017-07-08"
]
"time" => 149.01
]
]

If I print below:
print_r($queryResults);
echo "Count: ".$count;exit;

then o/p
  Array ( ) Count: 0
```

Why Am I getting $count value always '0'. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Add the outputted query: Reading to a bunch of if statements is not really working out when you don't know what you input. Also: Reduce to actually just that query. And last: Add a data example once you have the query

Comment: The query itself looks fine. You might have an issue with the way you define the two dates for the comparison, have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398921/how-does-sql-server-decide-format-for-implicit-datetime-conversion

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the table structure also. generally mysql Stores date format in YYYY-MM-DD, I am also checking for the same date format. Funny thing here is it is working fine in local server but not working in our server.

Comment: Seeing that there seems to be a different behaviour in the "local server" and "your server", have you tried specifying the dates in ISO format (`between '20170701' AND '20170708'`)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no luck its not working. If I run the same query in mysql server then it is not showing any error but giving empty result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is too late to post an answer but I hope this may help someone. The mistake which I made is in giving start date and end date formats like below:

Problem:

```
$start = "2017-07-01"
$end = "2017-07-08"
```

But Actually I have to give the input like below:

Solution:

```
$start = "2017-07-01 00:00:00"
$end = "2017-07-08 00:00:00"
```

My problem is solved after adding time as "00:00:00" to start and end dates. Thanks everyone.